# vba - clearing cells in excel with a button

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to make a button where I can clear all the cells in a range (e.g. B6:M10000) as well as a single cell (ie C3)

This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Sub ClearContents()

Range("B6:M100000" & "C3").Select
Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Goto Macro list and choose option to set a shortcut key to run your code.

Comment: Or you can also insert a shape in excel and right click it and assign your macro

Comment: you are referring to `Range("B6:M100000C3")` which is invalid  ... and, stop using `Select`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ClearContents()

    Range("B6:M100000, C3").ClearContents

End Sub
```